# Can I travel to the UK with a Belgian temporary residence card?

Tags: uk, belgium, identity-cards

Im a non-eroupean student living in Belgium with temporary resident permit identity card. Can I travel to the UK with this ID card?

Comment: No. It might make it more likely that you will get an UK visa, but you will need a visa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can’t answer that without knowing your citizenship. Your Belgian residence permit is irrelevant, it does not give you the right to enter the UK if you need a visa by virtue of your nationality. You can use this tool https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa to find out.

If you can enter the UK visa-free, you will need travel ID appropriate to your chosen transport and a passport to enter the UK https://www.gov.uk/uk-border-control/before-you-leave-for-the-uk